# How to check existing record field and compare with post data before change ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to MVC and hope someone can assist me.

I have a controller method to save post back data from a form. It has a field called OrderStatus. If the order status value is "Received" then only I want to execute a block of code.

What I am doing in this code is, read the post values and read the EF data again using Find and compare the values. All seems ok but when I try to save the record, it gives me below error.

```
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
```

I do understand the problem but how can I check the existing values in the database and compare and save.

My code is below

> ```
>     // POST: /Purchasing/Edit/5
>
>     [HttpPost]
>     public ActionResult Edit(PurchaseMaster purchasemaster)
>     {
>         if (ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>             if (purchasemaster.OrderStatus == "Received")
>             {
>                 string myId = purchasemaster.PurchaseId;
>                 //check if the existing status is already set as Received or not
>                 PurchaseMaster pm = db.PurchaseMasters.Find(myId);
>
>                 if (pm.OrderStatus != "Received") //this will prevent duplicate stock updates
>                 {
>                     //load the items and loop through to update the stock
>                     List<PurchaseDetail> purchasedetails = db.PurchaseDetails.Where(x => x.PurchaseId == myId).ToList();
>                     foreach (PurchaseDetail singleitem in purchasedetails)
>                     {
>                         string itemcode = singleitem.ItemCode;
>                         Item item = db.Items.Find(itemcode);
>                         item.QtyInHand = item.QtyInHand + singleitem.Quantity;
>                         db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
>                         db.SaveChanges();
>
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>
>             db.Entry(purchasemaster).State = EntityState.Modified;
>             db.SaveChanges();
>             return RedirectToAction("Index");
>         }
>         return View(purchasemaster);
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it should work

```
//don't get this object from database 
//PurchaseMaster pm = db.PurchaseMasters.Find(myId); 

if (db.PurchaseMasters.Any(x  =>x.Id == myId && x.OrderStatus != "Received") {
   // Do your stuff
}
```